# RxJava Subject as a pipe

Tags: mapping, pipe, rx-java

I want to use [Subject](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/wiki/Subject) to create essentially piping between one Observable to the next without the usage of [map](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/wiki/Transforming-Observables#map) or [flatMap](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/wiki/Transforming-Observables#flatmap) since using these is so verbose.

I can't figure out how to do this with Subject although this seems like it would be the right approach given that a Subject (according to the docs):

> acts both as an Subscriber and as an Observable

The signature is `Subject<T,R>` where it is an `Observable<R>` and an `Observer<T>`. This implies I should be able to pipe `T` to `R`.

Here's what it basically looks like in code:

```
class MySubject extends Subject<T, R> {

  protected MySubject(OnSubscribe<R> onSubscribe) {
    super(onSubscribe);
  }

  @Override public void onNext(T in) {
    // Data comes in
  }

  @Override public void onCompleted() {
    // do something
  }

  @Override public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
    // do something with the error
  }

}
```

Comment: Comparing with implementing a new `Subject`, it is easier to implement a function used in `map` or `flatMap`, isn't it?

Comment: @zsxwing It appears so. I learned that the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing with this in [Monifu](https://github.com/monifu/monifu) by feeding the observers in a flatMap manner (ignoring the fact that [PublishSubject](https://github.com/alexandru/monifu/blob/master/shared/monifu-rx/src/main/scala/monifu/reactive/subjects/PublishSubject.scala) is a final class). It should be similar in RxJava or RxScala:

```
class PipeSubject extends PublishSubject[RxEvent] {
  override def onNext(elem: RxEvent): Future[Ack] = {
    if (!isCompleted) {
      val observers = subscriptions
      if (observers.nonEmpty)
        pipeThroughMany(observers, elem)
      else
        Continue
    }
    else
      Cancel
  }

 private[this] def pipeThroughMany(array: Array[Observer[T]], elem: T): Future[Continue] = {
    val length = array.length
    def >>>(idx: Int = 0): Future[Continue] = {
      val obs = array(idx)
      obs.onNext(elem).flatMap {
         case Continue =>
           if (idx+1 < length)
              >>>(idx+1)
           else
             Continue
         case _ =>
           removeSubscription(obs)
           Continue
      }
    }
    >>>()
  }
}
```